# how to make wp7 map control zoom buttons easier to see

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, zooming, bing-maps

with windows phone 7 i am using teh bing map control.  i have it working just fine.  however, the zoom buttons (+,-) are at the bottom of the page and difficult to see.

The buttons have black border with black text.  They are easy to see on a light map background, but with black background they are in essence hidden.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make them easier to see?

Comment: add a screenshot. normally you would navigate the map by pinching the map. No need for + and - controls if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As invalidusername said you can use the pinching to zoom in and out and it is probably a better way to do it. But in my case I haven't a device or touch screen so needed to use buttons in this way to test my map.

Rather than using the built-in zoom buttons I looked at the sample code from this tutorial which has icons for zoom in/out and data bound them to the zooming of the map. Adapting it to my needs. It works pretty well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic2

You can change the positioning/images etc.

As per DanielBallinger's comment the link above seems to no longer work. The following does:

[Bing Maps Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic2#_Toc307127970)

Comment: Looks like the link has moved. I think the correct link is now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic2#_Toc307127970

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks for the update. That does indeed work. I will update my post